# MPMoviePlayerController on iPhone - Streaming or progressive download?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, webserver, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my iPhone App I need to show the videos which are in Flash format. 
I asked the client to change the videos in iPhone compatible format. They stored the converted the video on a server and I am able to show the video using MPMoviePlayerController.

Now we need to store around 25 videos (Each around 300 MB) and access them via iPhone App using MPMoviePlayerController

I have to help the client figure out how or where to host these files.
So some questions are there

1) What all things need to be taken care on server side for better performance? Is there any document available for this?
2) The video will be streaming or progressive download ? Do we have a choice?

I am sure many people would have done it. So kindly help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

if video is more then 10 minutes then you have to use streaming not progressive and you have to prepared playlist on server side with .m3u8 format. you just need to pass this url with .m3u8 into the mpmediaplayercontroller and this will take care of every thing from client side.
For server side functionality you can search apple code for streaming video.